# Proper Syntax for Filtering Expressions for Arrow Datasets in R

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I am attempting to use the `arrow` package *(relatively recently implemented)* DataSet API to to read a directory of files into memory, and leverage the `c++` back-end to filter rows and columns. I would like to use the `arrow` package functions directly, not the wrapper functions for `dplyr` style verbs. These functions are very early in their lifecycle as of today, so I'm having a hard time tracking down some examples that illustrate the syntax.

In order to understand the syntax, I have created a very minimal example for testing. The first two queries work as expected.

```
library(arrow) ## version 4.0.0

write.csv(mtcars,"ArrowTest_mtcars/mtcars.csv")
## Define a dataset object
DS <- arrow::open_dataset(sources = "ArrowTest_mtcars", format = "text")

## Generate a basic scanner 
AT <- DS$NewScan()$UseThreads()$Finish()$ToTable()
head(as.data.frame(AT), n = 3)
##                      mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
## 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

## Generate a basic scanner with projection to select columns
AT <- DS$NewScan()$UseThreads()$Project(c("mpg","cyl"))$Finish()$ToTable()
head(as.data.frame(AT), n = 3)    
#   mpg cyl
#1 21.0   6
#2 21.0   6
#3 22.8   4
```

However, I have not yet been able to figure out the proper syntax to implement a filtering expression. I've tried a number of things, but my best guess still isn't working, and causes a segfault when I execute the `Filt <- Expression$create(...)` line.

```
## Generate a basic scanner with filtering where column `cyl` = 6    
## My best guess at what might work, but causes a segfault instead
Filt <- Expression$create("==",args = list(Expression$field_ref("cyl"), Scalar$create(6L)))

AT <- DS$NewScan()$UseThreads()$Filter(Filt)$Finish()$ToTable()
head(as.data.frame(AT))
```

***What is the proper syntax to implement row based filtering?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation is quite awful on this. But a bit of trying and testing actually got me something that might lead you to the right answer. The problem I found was with `Scalar$create` ***and*** knowing which function to name to use:

```
Filt = Expression$create('or', 
                         args = list(Expression$field_ref("cyl") == 6L, 
                                     Expression$field_ref('cyl') == 4L))

AT <- DS$NewScan()$UseThreads()$Filter(Filt)$Finish()$ToTable()
head(as.data.frame(AT))
```

However, note that for a single condition just using `Expression$field_ref(...) == x` works directly in filter

```
AT <- DS$NewScan()$UseThreads()$Filter(Expression$field_ref("cyl") == 6L)$Finish()$ToTable()
head(as.data.frame(AT))
```

Comment: You got it right for both cases, the `head()` call I included just to make the example output brief  is why you were only getting 6 rows! How did you know to use `'or'` for the function name, and where might I find the other options? And to be fair to the project developers, I wouldn't say the documentation is awful, but rather could use some additional help to keep up with the break-neck pace at which new features and functionality are being added!

Comment: If you're going to manually build Expressions, you need the C++ function names. See [the C++ docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/compute.html#comparisons), or check out the [R source](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/df20489faaf0272e185ac20f39f65c1cb3d01083/r/R/expression.R#L118-L153), or in 4.0 you can call `list_compute_functions()`. The Expression classes aren't really documented because they're a bit burdensome to construct yourself (as you see), so we don't expect folks to do this. But if you want to contribute docs, please, we'd be happy to accept/review them.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @NealRichardson - I hope to be able to contribute some examples for docs (or perhaps a separate vignette) in the future, but for now I have a great deal of reading ahead just to make sure I have a solid grasp on best way to go about implementing various filters I need for a current project

Comment: I completely missed that you had added a call to `head`. That is my bad (:facepalm:). Great commend Neal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the avoidance of `dplyr`? I know one doesn't need to use it for general data manipulation on data.frames, but it's really useful for interfaces like these.

Comment: That would be for matt to answer. Personally using dplyr is preferred, as the effect on performance seems to be negligible

Comment: For my current project, speed, and memory efficiency are both high priorities, so I wanted to have a good understanding of how execution was taking place at a slightly lower level to make sure I wasn't leaving performance on the table _(this is my first project using `arrow` to fully cut Spark out of the processing pipeline)_. As I get a better understanding, I may still switch over to using the `dplyr` verbs, but I'm a little bit gunshy of taking any dependencies on `dplyr` after seeing numerous user facing breaking changes to the API over the years.

Comment: I can't speak to `dplyr`'s general stability, but in this particular case, if you're looking for API stability, I'd recommend using dplyr with arrow. `dplyr::filter()` is definitely stable, much more stable than Arrow's low-level APIs. And when we add features, we test that you get the same output when querying an Arrow Table as you do a data.frame with `dplyr`--so our strongest API guarantee is that things work as you expect with `dplyr`.

Comment: A bit late, but I appreciate both the ability to use `DS$NewScan()$...$ToTable()`, and the recommendation of `dplyr::collect(DS)` for its stability.

Answer (score 1):

help(open_dataset)

> " Call ‘open_dataset()’ to point to a directory of data files and return a
> ‘Dataset’, then use ‘dplyr’ methods to query it."'

Reproducible example sharding the iris dataset by species, then opening only one shard for the setosa species.

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
# Set up directory for examples
tf <- tempfile()
dir.create(tf)
on.exit(unlink(tf))

data <- dplyr::group_by(iris, Species)
write_dataset(data, tf)

# open only the setosa part
setosa <- open_dataset(tf) %>%
    filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
    collect()
```